# Why can't I make a reference to memory inside "if"?

Tags: rust

I could make a copy of this vector, but that will take time and memory.
I could write another `println`, but this is just an example — instead of `println` there may be several loops — and it will take space and complicate the code. I could perform the conversion in `main` and write two versions of the function call, but changing the reference is much easier.

```
fn foo(mut a: &Vec<i32>) {
    let mut c: Vec<i32>;

    if a[0] == 0 {
        c = vec![1; 3];
        a = &c;
    }

    println!("{:?}", a);
}

fn main() {
    let a: Vec<i32> = vec![0; 3];
    foo(&a);
}
```

Error:

```
main.rs:9:14: 9:15 error: `c` does not live long enough
main.rs:9         a = &c;
                       ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules of lifetime in rust are quite (very) strict: if you have a reference to an object, this object must live longer than the reference, **in both direction**.

This means the reference must be created **after the object**.

In your case, `a` exists before `c`, so the assignment `a = &c` is invalid. A simple fix can be to create a copy of the reference after `c` is created and work on this copy:

```
fn foo(vec_ref: &Vec<i32>){

    let mut c: Vec<i32>;
    let mut a = vec_ref

    if a[0] == 0 {
        c = vec![1; 3];
        a = &c;
    }
    println!("{:?}",a);
}
```

or in a more rusty way:

```
fn foo(vec_ref: &Vec<i32>){

    let mut c: Vec<i32>;
    let a = if vec_ref[0] == 0 {
        c = vec![1; 3];
        &c
    } else {
        vec_ref
    };
    println!("{:?}",a);
}
```

Comment: There is no need for copy, you can swap values of `c` and `a`.

Comment: I'm talking about copying *the reference* not the vector.

Comment: Ah, ok. But didn't OP wanted `ver_ref` to be mutated?

Comment: `mut a: &Vec<i32>` and `a: &mut Vec<i32>` are two very different things, and the OP was using the first one.

Comment: I assumed `mut a : &Vec<i32>` was an error. Does it have some special semantic different than `a: &Vec<i32>`?

Comment: Yes: it allows you to mutate the reference: change the object it points to.